# C# - Supporting different version of a program in the same source

Tags: c#

I'm building a program where lots of parts might be changed according to a version, and I would like to support these changes in the same source, being able to change just one or two lines of code to exchange between versions.

For example, let's say that I've the method Test, and for version 1:

```
public int Test() {
    int val = 1;
    val += 100;
    return val;
}
```

And for version 2:

```
public int Test() {
    int val = 1;
    val += 100;
    val *= 2;
    return val;
}
```

As C# doesn't support #define with values (so I could use #IF VERSION == 1 for example, the only way I thought to support this is to use a const, turning it into something like:

```
public int Test() {
    int val = 1;
    val += 100;
    if (version == 2)
        val *= 2;

    return val;
}
```

But would this be bad for perfomance if there're lots of changes like this?
Or does C# automatically ignore code that are unreachable? Or is there a better approach for this problem?

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more object oriented way would be to have split this code into two classes:

```
public interface IMyClass {
    int Test();
}

class MyClass1 : IMyClass {
    public virtual int Test() {
        int val = 1;
        val += 100;
        return val;
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
    public override int Test() {
        return 2*base.Test()
    }
}
```

External code would use IMyInterface and be completely ignorant about the actual implementation it was using.  You could then register the correct version for the interface using IoC Container or a factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an configuration on the `app.config` file to set this `version` flag. For sample, in your app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="version" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

So, you can read it.

```
int version = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"]);
```

and then you can use this `version` value to implement your method.

I am not sure it it is the case, but you can read the `Version` of a given assembly. For sample, to read the version of the assembly in execution, you can try this:

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

and you can check it:

```
if (version == "2.0.0.0")
{
   // something for version 2.0.0.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the versions by class instead, say TestClass with your method Test, and later on TestClass_2 with different behaviour of that method, you could easily achieve it using a Dependency Injection framework. You could replace your entire class being used in your application with just one line of setup code and recompile.

See https://simpleinjector.org/index.html as a reference/example